# Hostapd nl80211 failed to set interface -19

Tags: linux, debian, wifi-hotspot, hostapd, access-point

I am trying to run hostapd on Debian linux.
I am using a Realtek rtl8188 usb wifi card, on a Olimex OLinuXino A13 WiFi. 
However, when I run the command `hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` I am getting an error.

```
root@a13-OLinuXino:~# hostapd -dd /etc.hostapd/hostapd.conf
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
Could not open file /sys/class/net/wlan12/phy80211/name: No such file or directory
rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
nl80211: RFKILL status not available
netlink: Operstate: Linkmode=0, operstate=6
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 3 to mode 2: -19 (No such device)
nl80211: Try mode change after setting interface down
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 3 to mode 2: -19 (No such device)
nl80211: Interface mode change to 2 from 0 failed
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
```

This is the configuration file for hostapd:

```
root@a13-OLinuXino:~# cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=wlan12
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
country_code=NL
ssid=NAME
hw_mode=g
channel=3
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=PASSWORD
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Does *iw list* return any output? If so, what?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the `driver=nl80211` to [`driver=rtl871xdrv`](https://github.com/pritambaral/hostapd-rtl871xdrv) on your `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` file :

> Wifi chips like RT8188C and RT8192C, recognized as RTL8188CUS (or variants thereof) do not support the standard nl80211 driver of hostapd
>
> AP mode (via hostapd) support for wifi chips that identify themselves as RTL8188CUS (or variants thereof). If you've seen or heard someone claim that a certain wifi chip works with a special version of hostapd driver called `rtl871xdrv`, this is it.

Or you can install a custom  `hostapd` version with `nl80211` support :

```
apt-get remove hostapd
git clone https://github.com/jenssegers/RTL8188-hostapd.git
cd RTL8188-hostapd/hostapd
make
make install
```